# chaining operators in cdo

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate

I am calculating C factor by using the following equation:

C factor =1,                                        coverfraction= 0
C factor  =-0.083 xlg(coverfraction) + 0.417,            0 < coverfraction < 78.3%,
C factor= 0,                                        coverfraction > 78.3%,

To calculate the total  C factor, I apply part of the equation
C factor  = 0.417 − 0.083 × lg(coverfraction). But I dont know how to apply the conditions of cover fraction in the script using the cdo. In this case the log of all values is calculated including 0 and the values more than 78.3%.

The code is:

```
echo "Log: " $gc_ofile
cdo -O -L -log inputfile.nc ofilelog.nc
cdo -O -L "-mulc,-0.083" outputlogfile.nc ofilemulti.nc
cdo -O -L "-addc,0.417" ofilemulti.nc cfactor.nc
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, this still doesn't provide a completely [mre]. I suppose it would be useful to also provide a set of minimal input files and a comparison of the actual output with the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these kinds of operations it is often easier to use the `cdo` command `expr`

If the name of the coverfraction in the netcdf file (called coverfrac.nc) is exactly that then you can use expr like this:

```
cdo expr,'cfactor=0.417−0.083*log(coverfraction)' coverfrac.nc out1.nc
```

This will make a new variable "cfactor" as desired.

For the other part, this is where cdo's masking comes in (I'll be posting a video on this topic soon on my youtube climate unboxed channel and will update this post when the link is available).

So you can create a file with 0 everywhere that coverfraction is above 78.3% and 1 otherwise like this.

```
cdo lec,78.3 coverfrac.nc mask.nc
```

Now you need to multiply this by the first output file to set the result to zero where coverfrac> 78.3% and leave it unchanged otherwise.

```
cdo mul out1.nc mask.nc myfunction.nc
```